# remove index from UITableView while searching

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a UITable in order to search among some data (timezones). My problem is that when the overlay view comes up the index is still shown.

As shown in the image below the "?" character is shown and the index can be enabled. Is it possible to disable it when searching and the overlay is activated? How?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `sectionIndexTitlesForTableView` return `nil` when your search bar is active.

Answer (score 0):

Decrease your height of UITableView from the top

Comment: from your ViewContoller's xib

Answer (score 0):

Do you use UISearchDisplayController?

```
 - (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return (([[self.fetchedResultsController sectionIndexTitles] count] > 5) ? [self.fetchedResultsController sectionIndexTitles]:nil);
}
```

I show it when i have more than 5 results

Also this is a method of UITableViewDataSource. you need to implement and specify in header you implement ex :

```
UITableViewController<NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you refreshing the underlying tableview while the search table view is shown?
If you are, try to stop that. I had a similar problem which I was able to solve this way.